# Possible to deliver centrally configured login scripts on Linux?

Tags: linux, scripting, systemd, ldap, puppet

In Windows you can assign login scripts to users which run whenever they log into a system which allowing admins to do things like map drives/printers and generally do anything for which there isn't a premade tool or a way using group policy.

I can visualize how to replace a lot of group policy functionality by combining LDAP group memberships with puppet configuration but I can't approximate drive mappings. Autofs comes to mind, but to my knowledge it would only define certain directories that get mounted when you `cd` into them, not directories that get mounted when you log into a system and it wouldn't necessarily be for that particular user.

I looked into [logind](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html) for `systemd` platforms, but didn't seem anything that would get ran when a user logs in/out so I can't use puppet to drop a script somewhere and configure `logind` to run them as appropriate.

I'm also interested in catching people if they login via `gdm` or `kdm` so adding something to their `.bash_profile` might only be part of the solution. I've also toyed with the idea of putting a call to `pam_exec` into the PAM service files for the various sources I'm interested in, but I haven't had the time to write up a full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Which distribution are you using, and which shell? I suppose you are talking about graphical environment.

You might have success with using source directive in .bashrc, .bash_profile or .profile, or simply running the script in these by addressing it.

Comment: Shell is also something that complicate this. Vast majority of users will be using `bash` but there are a few using `zsh` and one or two using `fish`. Modifying the user's `.bash_profile` etc is also problematic because that's not easily done using puppet (that I'm aware of) so I'd have to do it manually for each user instead of en masse which is the desired effect.

Comment: using different shell complicates this... I am not familiar with zsh or fish, perhaps someone who is will chime in.

As for mass-modify, you could always just get a list of homedirs from /etc/passwd and loop through those.

Comment: One other thing would be to catch them if they login via the GUI. That sort of thing is why I started looking at `logind` since it looked like it would catch the user no matter where they're coming in from.